# three layer neural network for MNIST with Python

Tags: python, neural-network

I'm currently writing my own code to implement a single-hidden-layer neural network and test the model on MNIST dataset. But I got wired result(NLL is unacceptably high) though I checked my code for over 2 days without finding what's went wrong.

Here're global parameters:

```
layers = np.array([784, 300, 10])
learningRate = 0.01
momentum = 0.01
batch_size = 10000
num_of_batch = len(train_label)/batch_size
nepoch = 30
```

Softmax function definition:

```
def softmax(x):
    x = np.exp(x)
    x_sum = np.sum(x,axis=1) #shape = (nsamples,)
    for row_idx in range(len(x)):
        x[row_idx,:] /= x_sum[row_idx]
    return x
```

Sigmoid function definition:

```
def f(x):
    return 1.0/(1+np.exp(-x))
```

initialize w and b

```
k = np.vectorize(math.sqrt)(layers[0:-2]*layers[1:])
w1 = np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5, layers[0:2][::-1])
b1 = np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5, (1,layers[1]))
w2 = np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5, layers[1:3][::-1])
b2 = np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5, (1,layers[2]))
```

And the following is the core part for each mini-batch:

```
for idx in range(num_of_batch):

    # forward_vectorized
    x = train_set[idx*batch_size:(idx+1)*batch_size,:]
    y = Y[idx*batch_size:(idx+1)*batch_size,:]

    a1 = x
    a2 = f(np.dot(np.insert(a1,0,1,axis=1),np.insert(w1,0,b1,axis=1).T))
    a3  = softmax(np.dot(np.insert(a2,0,1,axis=1),np.insert(w2,0,b2,axis=1).T))

    # compute delta
    d3 = a3-y
    d2 = np.dot(d3,w2)*a2*(1.0-a2)

    # compute grad
    D2 = np.dot(d3.T,a2)
    D1 = np.dot(d2.T,a1)

    # update_parameters
    w1 = w1 - learningRate*(D1/batch_size + momentum*w1)
    b1 = b1 - learningRate*(np.sum(d2,axis=0)/batch_size)
    w2 = w2 - learningRate*(D2/batch_size+ momentum*w2)
    b2 = b2 - learningRate*(np.sum(d3,axis=0)/batch_size)

    e = -np.sum(y*np.log(a3))/batch_size
    err.append(e)
```

After one epoch(50,000 samples), I got the following sequence of e, which seems to be too large:

```
Out[1]:
    10000/50000     4.033538
    20000/50000     3.924567
    30000/50000     3.761105
    40000/50000     3.632708
    50000/50000     3.549212
```

I think the back_prop code should be correct and I couldn't find what's going wrong. It has tortured me for over 2 days.

Comment: I suggest you use pdb and a trivial test case to test your code, eg. is delta, gradient, update rule working right in each step. It's 4am now so I am not reading your code. Perhaps tomorrow (Of course, tmr may never come)

Comment: Why do you think that's bad after one epoch? It seems to be going down at a decent rate. Try at least 100 epochs and see where that gets you. People usually run thousands of epochs on MNIST.

Comment: @IVlad I ran 1 epoch and tested the model on test set, and get 85% error accuracy, I think that's bad enough in any sense. :(

Comment: @IVlad You maybe right, I re-ran my code through 100 epoch and reduced the error rate to 37%, I'll keep testing my code and figure out if there's any further problem. Thanks a lot, mate.

Comment: Yeah, don't start tests with large data sets. Start with XOR and basic functions to see if the components work properly (logging gradients and activations helps a lot as well). Try to test every mechanic of your network in an isolated fashion as far as you can. If you're still unable to train a specific set you need to tune your parameters so adjust the set size for shorter training times in order to find the "correct" parameters before you train the real thing.